# Java generics - method with "extends" typed collection parameter rejects valid argument?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand, why compiler rejects / accepts the following arguments.

I assumed, that both arguments would be accepted, because both Sets contain nothing, but children of Serializable. 
And being a child of Serializable - is the only thing, which is enforced by method signature **D extends Serializable** - right?

Why is the Set serializables1  of type **D extends Serializable** accepted? 
Why is the Set serializables2  of type **? extends Serializable** rejected? 
Why is **D extends Serializable** and **? extends Serializable** is not the same here?

```java
public class GenTest<D extends Serializable> {
    Set<D> serializables1;
    Set<? extends Serializable> serializables2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenTest<Serializable> g = null;

        g.accept(g.serializables1); // OK - WHY?
        g.accept(g.serializables2); // NOT OK - WHY?
    }

    void accept(Set<D> serializables) {}
}
```

Comment: Where is the `accept` method?

Comment: Sorry, added the method now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the signature, the `.accept()` method uses the class-scoped `D` type-parameter:

```
void accept(Set<D> serializables) {}
```

When instantiating `GenTest` as `GenTest<Serializable> g = null;` means that `D` will be replaced at Runtime with `Serializable`.

Now, what does `Set<? extends Serializable> serializables2` mean?

It means that `serializables2` can be assigned with a `Set` of *unknown* subclasses of `Serializable`. The compiler has no evidence that this *unknown* subclass will match the substitute of `D` at Runtime, and hence rejects to allow the code to compile.

Let's say you have these two types:

```
class A implements Serializable { }

class B implements Serializable { }
```

`Set<? extends Serializable> serializables2` means that `serializables2` can either be assigned with `Set<A>` or assigned with `Set<B>` at Runtime. Let's suppose it is assigned with `Set<B>`.

Now, if your `g.serializables` contain only objects of type `A` (which is possible, because the `D` is replaced by `Serializable`), this means that at Runtime you'll get a `ClassCastException`, when trying to pass a `Set<B>` to a method should be provided with a `Set<A>`.

More info:

- [Java Generics: What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 0):

When using `? extends Serializable` it can be an object of any class that implements `Serializable` and not just `D`, therefore it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<? extends Serializable>` says exactly that the set contains a type which inherits `Serializable` but is not known so you have a kind of backwards compatibility to the pre-generics days without the possibility of changing the set - and your compiler has no knowledge whether `?` complies to `D` in your example so he prohibits the given usage.

Answer (score 0):

serializables1 contains a "Set of D", accept() accepts a "Set of D". The type hierarchy of D is not important. serializables2 can be any Serializable. Casting down to D is not possible.

Comment: Why is the type hierarchy of D not important? 
Shouldnt the method accept children of D, because of polymorphism?